# RDBとkey-value型DBの使い分け

Tags: database, データベース設計

RDBとkey-value型DBはどう使い分ければよいでしょうか？
個人的にはインデックスを後から作れるかどうかの違いと認識していますがこれは正しいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

1. まず、理由がなければトランザクションを完備した仕組みを使用します。
   　結果的に十分に枯れた技術であるRDBになります。
2. 作ろうとしたシステムに対してRDB単体では必要なパフォーマンスを満たせない場合、部分的に別の仕組みを併用します。
   その際に、リアルタイムであればKeyValueStore等、非リアルタイムで膨大なデータの集計等であれば列指向DBと言ったNoSQLが候補に挙がります。